# Pandas filling a column using a function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question about filling a column in pandas using a function. Any help appreciated.
The idea is to simulate what the Profit/loss would be in a new column based on 2 predetermined values that are used in the function. Below is what i have so far, but i am not sure how to proceed.

Doing that, i am getting a Truth is ambiguous error. How can i fill the new column using the functions defined earlier?

[What the dataframe looks like before adding the new column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1xj7.png)

```
import pandas as pd 
fxContactSize = 100000
bid = 0.6821
ask = 0.6830

df = pd.read_excel("Template.xlsx")

def long_calc(lot, contract, closePrice, openPrice ):
    pnl = round((lot*contract)*(closePrice-openPrice), 2)
    return pnl

def short_calc(lot, contract, openPrice, closePrice):
    pnl = round((lot*contract)*(openPrice-closePrice),2)
    return pnl


df.insert(9, "SimulatedPnL", " ")
SimPnlCol = []
for x in df:
    if df['Type'] == 'sell':
        short_calc(lot= df['Volume'], contract=fxContactSize, openPrice=openPrice=df['Price'], closePrice=ask)
        SimPnlCol.append(short_calc)
    else:
        long_calc(lot= df['Volume'], contract=fxContactSize, openPrice=openPrice=df['Price'], closePrice=bid)
        SimPnlCol.append(long_calc)
    
df['SimulatedPnL'] = SimPnlCol
```

Comment: Look at using [numpy.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to replace the for loop and conditions. - `df['SimulatedPnL'] = np.select([df['Type'] == 'sell'], [short_calc(lot= df['Volume'], contract=fxContactSize, openPrice=openPrice=df['Price'], closePrice=ask)], long_calc(lot= df['Volume'], contract=fxContactSize, openPrice=openPrice=df['Price'], closePrice=bid))`

Answer (score 0):

You're running into issues by using both Series data and scalars. There are two places that are tripping you up.

1. the if else logic in your for-loop
2. the python round in your functions

If you instead of using the for-loop, used numpy where logic, and vectorized your functions by using pandas' round, you can clean this up a bit (and make it faster).

```py
def long_calc(lot, contract, closePrice, openPrice):
    return ((lot * contract) * (closePrice - openPrice)).round(2)


def short_calc(lot, contract, openPrice, closePrice):
    return ((lot * contract) * (openPrice - closePrice)).round(2)


df['SimulatedPnL'] = np.where(
    df['Type'] == 'sell',
    short_calc(
        lot=df['Volume'],
        contract=fxContactSize,
        openPrice=df['Price'],
        closePrice=ask,
    ),
    long_calc(
        lot=df['Volume'],
        contract=fxContactSize,
        openPrice=df['Price'],
        closePrice=bid,
    )
)
```

Comment: Hello Corey, this is the exact thing i was thinking about. Excellent reply. Thank you very much for the assist.